# what is observable equivalent of $q in angular 4? or empty Array in Observable.forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to create observable and return its value . I have function which upload some files one by one to server http post method usig `Observable.forkJoin` 
here is function

```
uploadDocument(data): Observable<any> {
let arr = [];
for (var it in data) {
  let input = new FormData();
  input.append("file", data[it].value);
  let files;
  if (data[it].enabled && data[it].value && data[it].value instanceof File) {
    arr.push(this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + 'Upload/File', input))
  }
}
console.log(arr)
if(arr.length==0){
  this.spinner.hide()
}
return Observable.forkJoin(arr);
 }
```

What I want to do . If array is empty I want to return observable with empty array or obj . 
here is my subscribe function

```
this.commonService.uploadDocument(this.DocsForm.controls)
  .subscribe(
           data=>{console.log(data)},
           error=>{console.log(error)}
    )
```

here data is array of return files path obj

Comment: `Observable.of([])`. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: what does .of do ? @JBNizet

Comment: I gave you a link to the documentation. Click on it, and read.

Comment: You can create an Observable from an object like @JBNizet said, or you can create one by yourself with Observable.create(observer => observer). Of caurse there are multiple other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: im just wondering what is `.of` can do because that docs too lengthy and im just beginner @Ore

Comment: Observable.of() creates a cold observable which delivers the value provided within the (). E.g. Observable.of({firstname: 'Jon'}).subscribe(value => console.log(value)); would print out the object {firstname: 'Jon'}. You may use this function when you have to return an observable but because a condition was met, you just need to return null or somewhat locally. A cache would be an example. If you have it in the cache return Observable.of(cachedObject) and otherwise do http.get(). I hope I was clear.

Comment: ok so please suggest me good approach I am stuck in it . array is just empty and it return nothing @Ore

Comment: If (lodash.isEmpty(data)) return Observable.of([]); 
return Observable.forkJoin(
data.map(file => this.uploadAFile(file)) /* returns the Observable given by http.post */
)

Comment: Make sure your data object is filled, remove the strange data[it] lines (you don't have to access data object, you already have the object in "it" which is filled by your iteratee. Etc. I think your code is buggy, not your use of forkJoin or the Observable library

Comment: thnx @Ore :) i did it  by pushing `arr.push(Observable.of(null));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forkjoin getting empty array and subscribe is not being invoked so I make a case for empty Array and return empty observable like this

```
  if(arr.length==0){
  this.spinner.hide()
  return Observable.of(null);
}
```